# How to replace characters in string Erlang?

Tags: regex, erlang

I have this piece of code that gets sessionid, make it a string, and then create a set with key as e.g. `{{1401,873063,143916},<0.16443.0>}` in redis. I'm trying replace `{` characters in this session with letter "a".

```
OldSessionID= io_lib:format("~p",[OldSession#session.sid]),
StringForOldSessionID = lists:flatten(OldSessionID),
ejabberd_redis:cmd([["SADD", StringForSessionID, StringForUserInfo]]);
```

I've tried this:

```
re:replace(N,"{","a",[global,{return,list}]).
```

Is this a good way of doing this? I read that regexp in Erlang is not a advised way of doing things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your solution works, and if you are comfortable with it, you should keep it.

On my side I prefer list comprehension : `[case X of ${ -> $a; _ -> X end || X <- StringForOldSessionID ]`. (just because I don't have to check the function documentation :o)

Comment: What if i want to delete character? Should i use $\d instead of $a?

Comment: In this case you can use a filter in the list comprehension, for example if you want to skip the character { : `[X || X <- StringForOldSessionID , X =/= ${]`.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> re:replace(N,"{","a",[global,{return,list}]).
> ```
>
> Is this a good way of doing this? I read that regexp in Erlang is not
>   a advised way of doing things.

According to [official documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html):

2.5  Myth: Strings are slow

Actually, string handling could be slow if done improperly. In Erlang, you'll have to think a little more about how the strings are used and choose an appropriate representation and **use the re module instead of the obsolete regexp module** if you are going to use regular expressions.

So, either you use re for strings, or:

leave { behind(using pattern matching)
if, say, N is {{1401,873063,143916},<0.16443.0>}, then

{{A,B,C},Pid} = N

And then format A,B,C,Pid into string.

Answer (score 0):

Since Erlang OTP 20.0 you can use [string:replace/3](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#replace-3) function from string module.

string:replace/3 - replaces SearchPattern in String with Replacement. 3rd function     parameter indicates whether the leading, the trailing or all encounters of SearchPattern are to be replaced.

```
string:replace(Input, "{", "a", all).
```