# Erlang regular expression to replace all occurrences

Tags: regex, erlang, python-re

I have given the following string:

```
S = "I want to replace {something} and {this}, too"
```

I want to replace everything inside curly brackets. (Brackets included). So that I get:

```
"I want to replace X and X, too"
```

I have some trouble understanding the re module in the official erlang docs. What I managed so far with

```
re:replace(S, "(\{.*?\})", "X", [{return, list}]).
```

is to get:

```
"I want to replace X and {this}, too"
```

How can I use `re:replace` so that all occurrences of the pattern are replaced?

Thank you!

Comment: check this out, you need to put global keyword :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034776/how-to-replace-characters-in-string-erlang

Comment: Thank you thats it! I missed this in the docs somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to @vinesh by providing the `global` option like:

```
re:replace(S, "(\{.*?\})", "X", [global, {return, list}]).
```